# Save temporary values deleted by reloadData in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple project with **`UITableViewCell`**, inside the Cell I have a **`UITextField`**, In my case I am creating rows of a table dynamically, ie:

When I call function **'AddField'** There is a counter that is responsible for storing the number of rows that the table must have.

```
-(void)AddField{

    numberOfRows++;
    [tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

So, if I type something in the first text field and then call the function to add more rows in the table, the row is added, another text field appear (leaving two), but the text entered in the first text field disappears due the command **`reloadData`**.

I Need help find the best way around this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: have you considered using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` rather than handling it yourself?

Comment: I will try this soon!

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a Mutable array to store all the typed values.

   [self.myMutableArray addObject:cell.textField.text];
2. In cell for Row at index path, get the text and set it back to the text field.

   cell.textField.text = self.myMutableArray[indexPath.row]